# Questions on Mathematical Writing

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question, closed-questions, asking-questions

Where should I ask about how to approach Mathematical paper writing? For example, the question [[How to write an abstract for a math paper?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210340/how-to-write-an-abstract-for-a-math-paper) ] was put on hold? Which stack exchange site should I have asked it on or is it completely inappropriate for the format of stack exchane

Comment: Probably academia.stackexchange.com, as many of the relevant issues in your question are not specific to mathematics.  Also, the question is a little broad and does not admit of a concise objective answer.  It's a good question, but not quite within the mandate of MathOverflow.  (Yes, we are still trying to figure out what that mandate is.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do that.